# supabase.Auth.CurrentSession returns null , c# client

Tags: c#, authentication, supabase, supabase-database

I'm using `dotnet add package supabase-csharp` as a c# client.
I'm signed in  `var session = await supabase.Auth.SignIn(email, password);` successfully, but when i tried to get the current user or session it get back as null:

```
var currentSession = _supabase.Auth.CurrentSession;
var currentUser = _supabase.Auth.CurrentUser;
```

The configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<Supabase.Client>(_ =>

new Supabase.Client(
    builder.Configuration["SUPABASE_URL"],
    builder.Configuration["SUPABASE_KEY"],
    new SupabaseOptions
    {
        AutoRefreshToken = true,
        AutoConnectRealtime = true,
    }));
```

Any hints related to this?

Comment: Instead of accessing them directly after login, try fetching them after login is complete. `var session = await _supabase.Auth.SignIn(email, password);

if (session != null)
{
    var currentSession = _supabase.Auth.CurrentSession;
    var currentUser = _supabase.Auth.CurrentUser;
}`

Comment: The idea is that i have separated endpoints for each action:  One controller for : `signup`, `signin`, `signout`. And another controller for :  `currentsession`, `currentuser`, `update`. 

Sample:

      [HttpGet("currentuser")]
    public IActionResult GetCurrentUser()
    {
        try
        {
            var currentUser = _supabase.Auth.CurrentUser;
            return Ok(currentUser);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { Error = $"Error getting current user: {ex.Message}" });
        }
    }